# Hot reload when working with Vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Is there a way to enable something like hot reload when working with single file Vue components in laravel? The laravel docs suggest `gulp watch`, but doesn't that mean I will have to kill the `laravel dev server` each time I make a change to a component? Is there a way to reload when I add (or make a change to) a component without having to stop the server and run the `gulp` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only need to issue the `gulp watch` command once, then it will continue to run. I don't know what system you're on but if you're using a Bash Terminal you can run it as a [background task](http://hacktux.com/bash/ampersand) using the Ampersand. You could also be running your development server as a backgrounded task, use [homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead), or open up two terminal windows.

Comment: I am running it on a Windows machine.